# Limit of sequence with discrete convolution $a_n = 1 - b * a$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convolution, cauchy-sequences

I have a sequence \begin{equation}

$a_n = 1 - \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}b_na_{n-i}$ where $b_n\leq{c}^n$, and $c<1$

Based on multiple simulations with varying parameters, I think that the sequence does converge to a limit and is indeed a Cauchy sequence.

Unfortunately, I'm unsure how to outline the proof. I've read about Young's inequality for convolutions multiple times, but I haven't found a way to apply it to this problem. Would it make sense to try proving convergence of the sequence via stability criteria for the corresponding LTI system (Z-Transformation..)?

[sample simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjPMl.jpg)

Any hint is appreciated

Comment: You have $a$ on the right and $a_n$ on the left of your first equation.  Do you intend this sort of circular reference?  When you write $\overline{b}$, do you mean the average value of $b$ or the complex conjugate of $b$?

Comment: $B(z)  = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b^n z^{-n} = \frac{z}{z-b}$ and $A(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n z^{-n}$, so $A(z)  (1+B(z)) = \frac{1}{z-b}  \implies \ldots$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform (aka discrete Laplace transform)

Comment: and $l_1$ filters are stable

Comment: @EricTowers, the reference is intended, but I stated the sequence more clearly now.

Comment: @user1952009: why is $A(z)=\sum \ldots$ ?

Comment: @Goofy : that's the Z transform, if $(a \ast b)_n = h_n$ then $A(z) B(z) = H(z)$ and if $H(z)/B(z)$ is a stable filter, then $a \in l_1$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$.